# Setting up consistency tests in FVM

Tags: finite-volume, verification

I am in need of some help to valdate a consistency test with a finite volume method solver.

The idea is the following:

Based on the method of manufactured solutions (MMS) I am supplying the analytical solution, $\mathbf{x}$,
I am letting the solver assemble the matrix, $\mathbf{A}$ from discretization, and I am supplying the source term, $\mathbf{b}$  (forcing term from MMS).

In the solving phase, I am computing: $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b}$.

and computing the following error norms:
$$
    L^{1}=\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left\vert \mathbf{r}\right\vert V_{i} }{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}V_{i}},
$$

$$
   L^{2}=\sqrt{\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(\mathbf{r}\right)^{2}V_{i} }{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}V_{i}}},
$$

$$
    L^{\infty}=\displaystyle\max_{i=1}^{N}\left\vert\ \mathbf{r}\right\vert,
$$

Where $N$, is the number of cells and $V_i$ is the cell volume.

By progressively refining the mesh, and using 2nd order discretization schemes, I am hopping that the residual $\mathbf{r}$ decreases with 2nd order accuracy.

Is this a suitable approach? My results are not showing the correct trend, the different norms have different orders-of-accuracy ($L^{1} = 3$, $L^{2}= 2.5$ and $L^{\infty} = 2$).

My MMS is: $T(x,y) = x^{2} + y^{2}$

The PDE is: $- \nabla \cdot (\Gamma \nabla T) = S_{T}$

The geometry is a rectangle defined with $x \in [-0.1, 0.7]$ and $y \in [0.2, 0.8]$.
The mesh is of uniform size and structured.
All boundary conditions are Dirichlet

Answer (score 1):

Generally you are on the right track. Double check your analytical solutions implementation and the norms. If you still get different orders of convergene then that is a strong indicator that there is a bug in your discretization (or boundary conditions!). I always recommmend to visualize the errors, sometimes that gives hints as to where the error lies (BC / processor boundaries etc.)

If you'd give us your PDE and your manufactured solutions we might be able to give you more feedback.

Comment: Sure. And thanks for the help!  I am going to make some changes to the post

Comment: Depending on the programming language you are using, it can be very convenient to use symbolic calculations to setup manufactured solution. Matlab as well as python offer such an option and this trick allows much more complex manufactured solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The point of using different norms is of course that each norm tolerates different kinds of error. The $L\infty$ norm responds to any large isolated error, so an obvious question to ask is where that largest error is found. Is there anything special about it?

As an aside, I am slightly skeptical about manufactured solutions because they introduce non-physical source terms. Are you sure how to discretize those?

Comment: The source term is just multiplied by the cell volume.

Comment: If you are using a physically-based scheme, source terms can create wave reflections.